# Как вычесть результат двух кодов в паскале

Tags: pascal

```
    Как объеденить эти два кода так что бы при решении этих задачь, выводилась разница.

program RIAD2;
    var
      i, n: integer;
      Y1: real;
    begin
      write('vvedite n= ');
      readln(n);
      Y1 := 1;
      for i := 3 to n - 1 do
        Y1 := Y1 + (1) * 1 / i;
      writeln('Y1=', Y2:8:4);
      readln;
    end.


program RIAD2;
var
  i, n: integer;
  Y2: real;

begin
  write('vvedite n= ');
  readln(n);
  Y2 := 1;
  for i := 2 to n do
    Y2 := Y2 + (1) * 1 / i;
  writeln('Y2=', Y2:8:4);
  readln;
end.
```

Обчислити значення YRez=Y1-Y2.

Answer (score 0):

Проверить нечем сейчас, но вроде так

```
program RIAD;
var
  i, j, n1, n2: integer;
  Y1, Y2, Y3: real;
begin
  write('vvedite n1= ');
  readln(n1);
  write('vvedite n2= ');
  readln(n2);
  Y1 := 1;
  for i := 3 to n1 - 1 do
    Y1 := Y1 + (1) * 1 / i;
  writeln('Y1=', Y2:8:4);

  Y2 := 1;
  for j := 2 to n2 do
    Y2 := Y2 + (1) * 1 / i;
  writeln('Y1=', Y2:8:4);
  readln;
  Y3 = Y1 - Y2;
   writeln(Y3);
end.
```

Comment: Спасибо, но единственная проблемма, когда я пишк н1 у меня при решении всегда выводит нули и значния не отнимаются